# Why can't I make item of clothing in the MakeHuman model?

Tags: animation

I export a model from MakeHuman to Blender. I have tried to make an item of clothing but when I click in the body [image]

and I change to Edit Mode [image]

Why?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is about? I may guess you are asking "why is the skin vanished?", but I'm a little bit confused abot the "clothing" part..

Comment: Thank you Carlo. When I try to make the item of clothing the body is  separate from the rings. I click in the body and I change to Edit Mode and then the ring is in the same position but the body is in the start position. I think I have to make the clothing before moving the model.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a imported MHX character from Makehuman.

[image]

It is already [rigged](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/index.html), so the mesh of the skin (which is just a surface) is somehow controlled by several handles.

There are a some ways in which a mesh can be rigged. In this case the character was built with an [Armature](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/armatures.html).
We can see in fact that the skin object (see the picture above for reference) has an [Armature Modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/armature.html) pointing to the armature (the top object of the hiererchy).

Every movement of the armature will be followed by a movement of the skin as defined by the armature's properties (bone weights, vertex groups, etc...).

When you switch from Object mode to **Edit mode**, the modifiers by default are not shown, so the skin doesn't follow the armature's deformation anymore. The mesh can be probably found near the origin in resting position.

[image]

You can edit the mesh "in place" by enabling the modifier visibiity for edit mode and adjusting the cage (see enabled options near the cursor)

[image]